# Writing custom links from array to Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following array in Google Sheets,
I'm using this code to write the array to the sheet:

```
let array = [["Dan", "www.dan.com", 65],["Sam", "www.sam.com",44],["Josh", "www.josh.com",10]];
let range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(1,1,array.length,array.length[0]);
range.setValues(array);
```

I want to be able to make a hyperlink for each instead showing the URL, for example "Josh Site" that leads to "www.josh.com"
Desired Output:

```
 |A    |B          |C    
1|Dan  | Dan Site  | 65
2|Sam  | Sam Site  | 44
3|Josh | Josh Site | 10
```

What's the best way to do that? if possible...

Comment: The easy what to do it is to use the hyperlink formula

Comment: The thing is when using the hyperlink formula I need to point on each range separately. I want to do it in bulk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function hlink() {
  let array = [["Dan", "www.dan.com", 65], ["Sam", "www.sam.com", 44], ["Josh", "www.josh.com", 10]].map(r => [r[0], `=HYPERLINK(\"${r[1]}\",\"${r[1]}\")`, r[2]]);
  let range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1, array.length, array[0].length).setValues(array);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. I though that I need to use setFormula to set it. Apparently not.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let array = [["Dan", "www.dan.com", 65],["Sam", "www.sam.com",44],["Josh", "www.josh.com",10]];
for (const row of array) {
  row[1] = `=HYPERLINK("${row[1]})","${row[0]} Site")`;
}
```